# How to correct error with netlify deployment

Tags: web-deployment, netlify

I'm having some issues deploying to netlify. And I would like to create a blog with template [cayman](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman)

1) In local host the site is operational

2) I push the website files on github

3) I'm connecting netlify to github repository

4) **But the deployment failed**

---

Log :

```
8:46:46 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
8:46:46 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
8:46:46 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
8:46:47 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
8:46:47 AM: git clone https://github.com/adrien1212/blog
8:46:47 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
8:46:48 AM: Starting build script
8:46:48 AM: Installing dependencies
8:46:49 AM: Downloading and installing node v8.15.0...
8:46:49 AM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.15.0/node-v8.15.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
8:46:49 AM:   0.9%
8:46:49 AM: 
#################
8:46:49 AM:                                           24.3%
8:46:49 AM: 
##########################################
8:46:49 AM: #########################       94.2%
######################################################################## 100.0%
8:46:49 AM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
8:46:49 AM: Checksums matched!
8:46:51 AM: Now using node v8.15.0 (npm v6.4.1)
8:46:52 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.3.6, read from environment
8:46:53 AM: Using ruby version 2.3.6
8:46:53 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
8:46:53 AM: Started restoring cached ruby gems
8:46:53 AM: Finished restoring cached ruby gems
8:46:53 AM: Installing gem bundle
8:46:53 AM: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
8:46:53 AM: Error during gem install
8:46:53 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:46:53 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
8:46:53 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:46:53 AM: Finished processing build request in 7.611237844s
```

I think the problem would come from here.

```
8:46:53 AM: Using ruby version 2.3.6
8:46:53 AM: Using PHP version 5.6

8:46:53 AM: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
```

But I can't figure out how to solve them. You can help me ?

Comment: I answered how to change your ruby version, but not sure what version you need. The default versions on netlify are going to be the fastest (in docs), but you may have a different requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**The way to change the ruby version on Netlify:**

Add a `.ruby-version` file to the root of your repository

`.ruby-version` (no final newline)
    2.4.3

You could instead use RUBY_VERSION environment variable, set in Netlify's UI in build & deploy settings or in `netlify.toml` (per Netlify support)

***Note:*** You choose from the [`rvm's`](https://rvm.io/) supported versions.

#### See what version of the bundler

**Change your build command on Netlify to output the bundle information:**

Use `bundle env && <your build command here>` for the build command

````bash
12:51:50 PM: Executing user command: bundle env && yarn build
12:51:50 PM: ## Environment
12:51:50 PM: ```
12:51:50 PM: Bundler             1.17.1
12:51:50 PM:   Platforms         ruby, x86_64-linux
12:51:50 PM: Ruby                2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-linux]
12:51:50 PM:   Full Path         /opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/bin/ruby
12:51:50 PM:   Config Dir        /etc
12:51:50 PM: RubyGems            2.6.14
12:51:50 PM:   Gem Home          /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3
12:51:50 PM:   Gem Path          /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3:/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3@global
12:51:50 PM:   User Path         /opt/buildhome/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
12:51:50 PM:   Bin Dir           /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bin
12:51:50 PM: Tools
12:51:50 PM:   Git               2.19.1
12:51:50 PM:   RVM               1.29.4 (latest)
12:51:50 PM:   rbenv             not installed
12:51:50 PM:   chruby            not installed
12:51:50 PM:   rubygems-bundler  (1.4.5)
12:51:50 PM: ```
````

Comment: I'm created the .ruby-version with `echo 2.4.3 > .ruby-version` but I want to put the file .ruby-version on github Ihave the error : _This file is hidden._ but in this file there is _2.4.3_

Comment: If that filename is problematic (it shouldn't be, not sure why you get that message), you can instead use RUBY_VERSION environment variable, set in Netlify's UI in build & deploy settings or in netlify.toml (cf https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/)

Comment: Seems kinda weird that you would get that error. I will have to test it sometime.